# AssertionError with custom user model django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm new to django, recently i decide to integrate django allauth for using login with (facebook and google+), i work with a custom model (django 1.5), and a one to one userprofile model, my custom model class looks

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):   
   email = models.EmailField(
      verbose_name='email address',
      max_length=255,
      unique=True,
      db_index=True,
   )
   username = models.CharField(max_length=35,  blank=False)
   is_active = models.BooleanField (default=False)
   is_admin = models.BooleanField (default=False)

  objects = MyUserManager()

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

and my user profile :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   phone = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
   is_visible = models.BooleanField (default=True)
   user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, primary_key=True)
```

here the django allauth local_settings file :

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'bloodi.accounts.forms.RegistrationForm'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
```

with this configuration i met two problems with django allauth :
   *) It doesn't allow a duplicate username 
   *) the application crash on sign up process  ( it seems like the user account must be active to continue to login)

```
AssertionError 
Exception Location: \allauth\account\utils.py in perform_login, line 110
...
assert user.is_active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate usernames are not allowed by Django, see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD

As for the assertion error, use:

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, 
i want the application accepts two users with the same username but not email, that's why i use USERNAME_FIELD as 'email' but with the registration of allauth form raise with error "the username already taken", thanks for advance.

Comment: Ok, then in your project you do not seem to have a true `username`, only something like a `nickname`. In that case, set `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD` to `None` ...